# Combine matching arrays by values into new array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a simple array *$simpleArray* with ids inside.

```
1
   id="1"  
2
   id="3"  
3
   id="7"
```

I have another array *$complexArray* with several variables inside:

```
1
   id="1"  
   color="blue"
   size="7"
   height="10"
2
   id="2"  
   color="red"
   size="64"
   height="52"
3   
   id="3"  
   color="pink"
   size="72"
   height="39"
```

I want to create a third array called *$mixedArray* which is a sub-set of *$complexArray* such that if *id* is in *$simpleArray*, that row appears in *$mixedArray*. In the above example, the new array would be:

```
$mixedArray =
1
    id="1"  
    color="blue"
    size="7"
    height="10"
2
    id="3"  
    color="pink"
    size="72"
    height="39"
```

I tried the following:

```
foreach ($simpleArray as $complexArray){

    $mixedArray [] = array("id"=>$complexArray['id'],
                           "color"=>$complexArray['color'],
                           "size"=>$complexArray['size'],
                           "height"=>$complexArray['height']); 
}

print_r($mixedArray);
```

Comment: Could you edit the post and actually ask a question?

Comment: updated title for concision, text for readability, and line breaks in code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$mixedArray = array();
foreach ($complexArray as $element){
    if(in_array($element['id'], $simpleArray)){
        array_push($mixedArray, $element);
    }
}
```

So, what it does is it checks if the id of the current complexElement is inside of the simpleArray, and if it is it pushes that element into the mixedArray

Answer (score 0):

Try below logic:

Check simple array id in complex array and if exist assign in mixedArray. for that you can use **in_array : Returns TRUE if value is found in the array, FALSE otherwise**.

```
foreach ($complexArray AS $complexArray1){
if (in_array($complexArray1['id'], $simpleArray) {
$mixedArray [] = $complexArray1;
}
}
print_r($mixedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will help:

```
function  getMatching($id, $simpleArr){
    $found = 0;
    foreach($simpleArr as $v){
        if($v['id'] == $id){
           $found = 1; 
           break;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}
$mixedArr = array();
foreach($complexArr as $ck=>$cv){
    $match = getMatching($cv['id'], $simpleArr);
    if($match){
        $mixedArr[] = $cv;
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($mixedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to this problem.

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$allowed = array_flip(array_column($simpleArray, 'id'));

$result = array_filter($complexArray, function ($item) use ($allowed) {
    return isset($allowed[$item['id']]);
});
```

Or you can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$allowed = array_flip(array_column($simpleArray, 'id'));

$result = array_intersect_key(
    array_combine(array_column($complexArray, 'id'), $complexArray),
    $allowed
);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55a90f07717816a56290ba459eb4ba8a1960b3cf).

Answer (score 0):

@ian you can also do it with foreach() with in_array() condition with the help of array_column() like below:

```
<?php
    foreach($complexArray  as $value){
        if(in_array($value["id"], array_column($simpleArray, "id"))){
            $mixedArray[] = $value;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mixedArray);
```